# wörtlich - "literally" or intensifier?

Tags: meaning

I have read in [DW news](https://www.dw.com/de/22072020-langsam-gesprochene-nachrichten/a-54260662):

> Präsident Donald Trump hat die US-Amerikaner vor einer weiteren Zuspitzung der Pandemie gewarnt. "Es wird wahrscheinlich leider schlimmer werden, bevor es besser wird", sagte Trump wörtlich bei seinem ersten Corona-Briefing im Weißen Haus seit Ende April

What does "wörtlich" mean here? Is it some kind of intensifier, as mentioned in ['Wörtlich' unwörtlich](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36718)? The usual translation "literally" does not make sense to me, as I see no ambiguity in the quoted sentence. I often see this word used with quotes in various contexts in German news.

Comment: [verbatim](https://www.dict.cc/german-english/w%C3%B6rtlich.html)

Comment: @Olafant -- I'm confused about that; Google Translate translates it as "verbatim", is that wrong?

Comment: @RDBury No. That's not wrong. That's as close as you can get, I think.

Comment: @Olafant -- In that case, since this is (as pointed out below) the transcript of an audio program where you can't see quotation marks, it seems like *wörtlich* is completely appropriate here and has nothing to do with hyperbole or intensifiers or the like. In English you'd say "Quote (the quote) unquote", so apparently this is just how you do the same thing in German, though I gather *Zitat:* is used more often.

Comment: @RDBury Well, yes. It's a translation though.

Comment: I am not an expert. But as a native German speaker this sounds like the DW usage of "wörtlich" is at least borderline incorrect. To my ears "wörtlich" means these are the words that Mr. Trump spoke. Which is clearly not true.

Comment: @user2705196 -- Agreed. Per the Financial Times: Trump says coronavirus will ‘get worse before it gets better’. It's actually a common expression in English, but it does seem to lose a bit in translation. But I think DW's audience is going to know that the *wörtlich* shouldn't be taken completely literally.Otherwise DW would have to explain on every quote from a foreign leader that it's been translated, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: @RDBury That we are reading the transcript of an audio  broadcast is the crucial information here. It is unlikely that anybody would write this way -- the quotation marks make "wörtlich" redundant to a degree that makes you wonder whether it was used in some other meaning.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The intensifier you are suggesting in German is probably:

> buchstäblich, see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/buchst%C3%A4blich).

*Wörtlich* (English: *verbatim*) would mean an actual citation. Considering that Trump spoke in English, a translation had tobe applied, so I consider it a bit of a stretch to the meaning of *wörtlich*. It restricts here to the meaning, that the sentence was not paraphrased but closely translated.

Update: this leads to more likely explanation (than stretched meaning) : Deutsche Welle is originally a radio broadcaster, the link is a transcript of a radio news broadcast. *Wörtlich* is the counterpiece of quotes on the audio channel, it is also frequently used in TV news.

Comment: The quotes already imply that the sentence was closely translated, so using an additional word to express it seems redundant. That's why I see "wörtlich" as an intensifier in this context.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista, redundancy is a normal part of human communication. Of course you can always consider it an intensifier if you so choose. Also, quotation marks are not present in speech.

Comment: +1 This, the use of "wörtlich" in this quote should be translated with "verbatim". It is not an intensifier (at least I, as German native speaker, do not understand it like this). In contrast to this, "literally" (as intensifier) may be better translated as "sprichwörtlich" or "regelrecht", or less metaphoric, just "(genau) so".

Comment: Sorry for the down vote, but from my point-of-view the question is not focused on the fact that there was a translation from English to German. It is rather related to the question when *wörtlich* is used in German. And it is necessary to explain the difference between *wörtlich* used by German speaking people and *literally* used by English speaking people which is now also widely used to mean the same as "bildlich" in German.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that "verbatim" is a more precise translation of "wörtlich" and that quotation marks are not present in speech. Even in the case of speech, I still see "wörtlich" as redundant in the aforementioned text because it is clear that the sentence is a quote when a narrator says "Ich sage etwas, sagte X". A proof of such assertion is that several other quotes from the same news website do not use "wörtlich" or any synonym of it. Nevertheless, redundancy is indeed common in natural languages, as mentioned by @CarstenS.

Answer (score 7):

In English *literally* has been used to emphasize something for quite a long time. Although it originally was meant to be used differently and this kind of usage is often referred to as *wrong* in literature it has until now been widely accepted. E.g. to say

> This literally broke my heart into tiny pieces.

would mean, if you follow strict grammar rules, that my heart *really* broke into tiny pieces (which would have killed me). But everybody knows that literally was just used to express the significance of the situation and how sad it made me feel.

In German language *wörtlich*, *wortwörtlich* or also *buchstäblich*, although translated to *literally* in dictionaries, is used to express that someone really means it exactly the way they said it or wrote it down. For instance, when quoting someone correctly just the way they said it.

So in your example the journalist wants to express that Trump really said this with these exact words.
See also https://www.wortbedeutung.info/w%C3%B6rtlich/

If you wanted to express the opposite in German language, which would by strict rules refer to *metaphorical* in English, you would use the word *bildlich*. E.g.

> Die Politiker haben dieses Gesetz, bildlich gesprochen, geradezu kopflos beschlossen.

This does not mean that the politicians decided to pass the legislation without having their heads on their shoulders but without thinking it through very well.

The embedded sentence *bildlich gesprochen* may also be omitted and often is when well known phrases are used.

So if we now reconsider the previous example when following strict rules it should rather be something like:

> This broke my heart into tiny pieces, metaphorically speaking.

Comment: Since the hyperbolic usage of _literally_ is already so common and wide-spread, I think it's wrong to call it wrong. The term just has acquired an additional meaning (or rather, function). Similar to how _billig_ went from "appropriate" (positive connotation) to "cheap" (bad connotation). Otherwise you're totally correct.

Comment: You're right, I rephrased the explanation at the beginning a little bit.

Comment: " ...  if you follow strict grammar rules ... " I think this has nothing to do with grammar.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote; you give a pretty good explanation, how and why *wörtlich* could mean an emphasis without questioning that assumption; as you can see in my answer, I don't agree with it.